# JavaScript - create a grid of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array of random numbers 1-10 and would like to create 10 arrays, each of them starting with a number from the random array like so:

```
const shuffled = [3, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1, 10, 4, 9, 5];

let rGrid = [];

// populate arrays
for (let x of shuffled) {
  rGrid[x-1] = new Array(10);
  rGrid[x-1][0] = x;
}
console.log(rGrid);
```

So ultimately I would like:

```
array1: 3,,,,,,,,,,,,
array2: 6,,,,,,,,,,,,
array3: 8,,,,,,,,,,,,
etc.
```

The code I have places ordered numbers 1-10 as first elements of arrays:

```
array1: 1,,,,,,,,,,,
array2: 2,,,,,,,,,,,
array3: 3,,,,,,,,,,
```

Please advise.
Here's a code pen:
http://codepen.io/wasteland/pen/QdvwJj?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a new array for each element of `shuffled` and set the first element to the actual number.

```js
var shuffled = [3, 6, 8, 2, 7, 1, 10, 4, 9, 5],
    array = shuffled.map(a => {
        var r = new Array(10);
        r[0] = a;
        return r;
    });

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
   rgrid = [] 
   for x in shuffled
       var temp = []
       temp.push(x)
       for i < shuffled.length-1
         temp.push("")
       rgrid.push(temp)

  console.log(rgrid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let rGrid = [], 
    i = 0;
shuffled.forEach(function(each){
    let arr = new Array(10);

    arr[0] = each;

    rGrid.push(arr);
});
```